# Why are there tiny air bubbles in the water of my toilet tank?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Why there are there tiny air bubbles in my toilet water tank? Is it a sign of leaking?

What causes these bubbles and how can it be fixed?

Comment: If bubbles are on the outside,  it is most likely just condescension.  Cold water is cooling tank and air moisture is forming on tank.  Same as taking a cold bottle out of fridge on a hot day.  A long time ago in a galaxy far away, there where insulation kits for toilets.  Forget now if they went inside or outside.

Comment: @crip659 styrofoam panels inside the tank

Comment: @Lost I find it absolutely amazing that you do not know about water condensation on cold objects? .... do you live in a place where it is hot most of the year? ... don't you see drops of water forming on a bathroom mirror when you have a hot shower?

Comment: Your bathroom is too humid. Keep better ventilation may alleviate the problem.

Comment: @crip659 I think there is a chance you mean condensation.

Comment: The bubble is inside the tank not outside, and I also find that the overflow tube has water sitting there and constantly moving, so finally, I turn off the water main valve for a day and next the all the water was drained, so there was a secret leaking silently and if I didn't notice or close the valve the water get drain silently and then get a refill and nobody even knows and our water bills get high $$$$$$$, these things are very tricky sometimes, anyway I just bought it from Hoe depot so will return and buy another one. Anyway thanks to all who try to tease and who try to decently reply to

Comment: The bubbles are just air bubbles naturally forming at nucleation sites on the foam.  If the toilet keeps flowing even though it's already full, you should check your stopcock and or float valve.  If the bowl keeps filling from the tank, you should check the tank flapper valve.  You should edit your question to include this additional information.

Comment: @KH: Agreed. Bubbles adhering to surfaces is not uncommon, and is harmless. Ignore it.